# Build command failed.Error while executing process

Tags: android, c++, gradle, cmake, ndk-build

I'm trying to export a .apk file from Android Studio and I already did this

"1. In your project pane, right-click on your module, and select Link C++ Project with Gradle.
2 .From the drop-down select either CMake or ndk-build, depending on your project

a. If you selected CMake, specify the CMakeLists.txt script in your project

b. If you selected ndk-build, specify the Android.mk."

(I just copy pasted the answer from @Janman)

This is the error

> Save New Duplicate & Edit Just Text Twitter
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   6
>   7
>   8
>   9
>   10
>   11
>   12
>   Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process C:\Users\costy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\costy\AndroidStudioProjects\android1\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/costy/AndroidStudioProjects/android1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\costy\AndroidStudioProjects\android1\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib C:/Users/costy/AndroidStudioProjects/android1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86_64/libplayer_shared.so}
>   Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in C:\Users\costy\AndroidStudioProjects\android1\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\Android.mk for module player_shared
>   Android NDK:   C:\Users\costy\AndroidStudioProjects\android1\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk C:\Users\costy\AndroidStudioProjects\android1\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk C:\Users\costy\AndroidStudioProjects\android1\app\src\main\jni\list.sh
>   [x86_64] Compile++      : player_shared <= main.cpp
>   C:\Users\costy\AndroidStudioProjects\android1\app\src\main\jni\main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'PTPAppDelegate.h' file not found #include "PTPAppDelegate.h"
>   1 error generated.
>   make: *** [C:/Users/costy/AndroidStudioProjects/android1/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/x86_64/objs-debug/player_shared/C_\Users\costy\AndroidStudioProjects\android1\app\src\main\jni\main.o] Error 1

Android Gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}


 allprojects {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
       google()
}
```

App Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.glitchrun.sapphire"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 26

    ndk {
        moduleName "player_shared"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path file('build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk')
    }
}


dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
   compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
   compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
   compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
   compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect the code and the error message, related to the problem, to be **in the question post** itself, as **text**, not linked as *image*. Please, [edit] your question post and fix that issue. You may format inserted code and the error message with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: I understand this but it's a long code and the error is huge. @Tsyvarev

Comment: @AlexandruCostin If so, then you should make a [mcve].

Comment: Neither of text contained in your images is "huge" for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think I fixed my post now, thanks.

Comment: Please, do not use **blockquote** formatting for error messages. This formatting doesn't preserve newlines, so the error message becomes difficult to undestand. Format error message in the same way as a **code**.